# Laravel URL Route get 2 parameter

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I need to delete a photo from an Album so I think I need 2 parameter on Routing
but I get some error please give me solution or another way to delete a photo from an album

here's my Routes.php :

```
Route::get('/admin/album/{albumid}/{id}/delete-photo', array(
    'as' => 'admin-photo-delete',
    'uses' => 'GalleryController@deletePhoto'
));
```

and call a function deletePhoto on GalleryController, here's GalleryController :

```
public function deletePhoto($albumID,$photoID){
$photo = Album::find($albumID)->photo()->where('id','=',$photoID)->get();
if($photo){
    File::delete(public_path().'/assets/images/gallery/'.$photo->images);
    $photo->delete();
    return Redirect::route('admin-gallery')->with('message','Photo was deleted successfully');
}
return Redirect::route('admin-gallery')->with('message','Photo delete failed');}
```

and here how I call route :

```
 <a href="{{URL::route('admin-photo-delete',$id,$photo->id)}}">Delete Photo</a>
```

I already make sure that $id and $photo->id was not null but see what url showing there's no second parameter value so I get some error:
[image]

Comment: In the URL there is 2 backslashes before 'delete-photo'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In `URL::route`, you should use an array as the second parameter, like this:

```
<a href="{{URL::route('admin-photo-delete', [$id, $photo->id] )}}">Delete Photo</a>
```